# F# Tree recursion & compute results while traversing back from leaf

Tags: f#, tree, tail-recursion

I am looking for some pointers/snippets to resolve below task.

```
type Rel = 
{
  id:int,
  from:int,
  to:int,
  percent:float
  IsLeafNode:string
}
```

I have below data

```
id  from to percent isLeafNode`

1   A    B  0.6     N

2   A    C  0.4     N

3   B    D  0.2     N

4   B    E  0.8     Y

5   C    F  1.0     N

6   D    G  1.0     Y

7   F    H  0.7     Y

8   F    B  0.3     N

9   I    J  1.0     N

10  J    K  1.0     Y
```

I need to build a tree or graph like relationship between from and to values and   multiply percentages from some specific nodes (A and I in this case) to leaf nodes and figure out starting id to leaf level Id and computed percentage. I am looking for below results

```
1 - 6 (A to G via B,D)       = 0.6 * 0.2 * 1.0 = 0.12

1 - 4 (A to E via B)         = 0.6 * 0.8 = 0.48

1 - 7 (A to H via C,F)       = 0.4 * 1.0 * 0.7 = 0.28

1 - 6 (A to G via C,F,B,D,G) = 0.4 * 1.0 * 0.3 * 0.2 * 1.0 = 0.024

1 - 4 (A to E via C,F,B,E)   = 0.4 * 1.0 * 0.3 * 0.8 = 0.096

9 - 10(I to K via J)         = 1.0 * 1.0 = 1.0
```

I am trying to figure what will be right type of structure to use and how to use some of already resolved nodes e.g. B already resolved while resolving left side of A; F to B should be able to use already computed B to G and B to E percentages. I have lot of data to process using this approach and it could be up to 50 levels deep.

just taking first few nodes, here is what I am doing

```
type internal LeafNode
{
    ID:int;
    to:string;
    percent:float;
}

type internal ChurnNode =
{
    ID:int;
    from:string;
    percent:float;
}

type internal Tree<'L,'N> =
    | Leaf of 'L
    | Node of 'N * Tree<'L,'N> seq

type internal Eq = Tree<LeafNode, ChurnNode>

let rec Fold fLeaf fNode acc (tree: Tree<'L,'N>) : 'r =
    let recurse = Fold fLeaf fNode
    match tree with
        | Leaf leafInfo ->
            fLeaf acc leafINfo
        | Node (nodeInfo, children) ->
             let localAcc = fNode acc nodeInfo
             let finalAcc = children |> Seq.fold recurse localAcc
             finalAcc  //return

let ComputePercent eq =
    let fleaf acc (leaf:LeafNode) =
        acc * leaf.percent
    let fNode acc (node:ChurnNode) =
        acc * node.percent
    Fold fleaf fNode 1.0 eq

let RunProcess() =
    let nodeA = {ID=0;from="A";percent=1.0}
    let nodeB = {ID=1;from="B";percent=0.6} 
    let leafC = {ID=2;to="C";percent=0.4}
    let leafD = {ID=2;to="D";percent=0.2}
    let leafE = {ID=2;to="E";percent=0.8}

    let t = Node(nodeA, [NodeB, [Leaf(leafD); Leaf(leafE)]; Leaf(leafC)]

    t |> ComputePercentage
```

For A to B to D & E, this code returns 1.0 * 0.6 * 0.2 * 0.8 but I need A to B to D = 1.0 * 0.6 * 0.2 and A to B to E = 1.0 * 0.6 * 0.8. Can you let me how how to reset the accumulator when done with a leaf. May be I got off wrong foot here but it's bit tricky for me.